# run docker build in cmake

Tags: docker, cmake

I'm trying to build the docker image in cmake with the following:

```
add_custom_target(module_tests
  COMMAND cp -r ${FFMPEG} .
  COMMAND cp ${FFMPEG_SO_INSTALL} ${FFMPEG}/lib
  COMMAND docker build -t moduletest -f Dockerfile .
)
```

But I got error saying `/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found`, while running docker build manually works.

Comment: Which [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) (or build utility) do you use for build the project? It is possible that environment, which is used during the build, doesn't contain `docker` executable in its `PATH` variable. Note, you may use [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_program.html) command for find *absolute path* of the `docker`, and run it using this path. This wouldn't depend from the build environment.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on the [excellent comment of Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474255/run-docker-build-in-cmake#comment89920358_51474255), your code should look more like

```
find_program(Docker_EXECUTABLE docker)
if(NOT Docker_EXECUTABLE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find the docker executable!")
endif()
add_custom_target(module_tests
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${FFMPEG} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${FFMPEG_SO_INSTALL} ${FFMPEG}/lib
    COMMAND ${Docker_EXECUTABLE} build --tag moduletest --file
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Dockerfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)
```

This code is portable across platform. Moreover, this code will generate a clear error message during *CMake time*, i.e. very early, if **Docker** is not found.

Finally, getting to the point of your question, the [documentation of find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/find_program.html) explains how it works and where it looks to find programs. For instance, you'll see that the paths in the variable `CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH` are searched, so something you could do is `which docker` from a shell, and then, using the path that `which` printed, you could call `cmake` using a command like

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH=/dockerDirectory/printed/by/which ..
```

assuming that the `CMakeLists.txt` is in the directory `..`

Bonus: Consider using `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different` instead of `copy`.

Comment: Incidentally, I personally would avoid copying to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` and instead set things up to copy to and work with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` (or something based on that) so out-of-source builds will work.